# NSLog not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nslog

I'm trying to let the NSLog print out the JSON data. but it wont show up on log. I'm new to  Objective-C. What must be wrong with the code?

```
@implementation demo2ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   title = @"title";
   thumbnail = @"thumbnail";
   author = @"author";

   myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
// note : i have the ip address, but stackoverflow wont allow me to post it. so i deleted.


    NSArray*  jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                      jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers  error:nil];

    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
        NSString *title_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *thumbnail_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
        NSString *author_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"author"];

        NSLog(@"TITLE: %@",title_data);
        NSLog(@"THUMBNAIL: %@",thumbnail_data);
        NSLog(@"AUTHOR: %@",author_data);

        dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      title_data, title,
                      thumbnail_data, thumbnail,
                      author_data,author,
                      nil];
        [myObject addObject:dictionary];
    }
}

[ { 
title: "Post From Wordpress Title", 
content: "Some Content from Post on Wordpress", 
author: "Banyapon Poolsawasd", thumbnail: "" 
},{ 
title: "Post From Wordpress Title", 
content: "Some Content from Post on Wordpress", 
author: "Banyapon Poolsawasd", 
thumbnail: "" 
 } ]
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: below is the json data

Comment: YOu are not passing any urlString ` NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];`

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your nslog statements to be sure they are even being executed.

Comment: check wether jsonObjects array contain object or its nil

Comment: maybe try to use NSLog([dataDict allKeys]); to see if your dataDict has all those keys such as "title", "thumbnail" in it. If not, maybe something wrong with your json objects.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Read the comment in the code about the URL.

Comment: If none of the logs are showing then the loop isn't being entered. This means that `jsonObjects` is `nil` or `empty. Make use of the `error` parameter on the call to `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`. If `jsonObjects` is `nil`, log the error.

Comment: Make sure you are getting a response from your URL - i.e. check if jsonSource is not null (check the size - it might be a 404 error or something).  ALso, why use NSData - can't you just get a string from your website?

Comment: i tried putting  NSLog(@"jsonObjects%@", jsonObjects); the response was : 2014-02-05 12:37:16.801 demo2[23908:15d03] jsonObjects(null)

Answer (score 0):

Try to NSLog to jsonSource

```
NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    [NSURL URLWithString:@""]]; //Here you are not call url string
NSlog(@"jsonSource:%@", jsonSource);
```

jsonSource will return nil

```
    NSArray*  jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers  error:nil];

 NSlog(@"jsonObjects:%@", jsonObjects);
```

jsonObjects will also return nil

so controller does not goes inside for loop that is the reason you slog not printed..

Comment: when i do this   
    NSString *pageSource = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonSource encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"page source%@",pageSource);

Comment: it will return 2014-02-05 12:37:16.771 demo2[23908:15d03] page source [ {
   
   title: "Post From Wordpress Title",
   
   content: "Some Content from Post on Wordpress",
 
   author: "Banyapon Poolsawasd",
   thumbnail: "http://www.youweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/image.png"
   
  },{
   
   title: "Post From Wordpress Title",
  
   content: "Some Content from Post on Wordpress",
  
   author: "Banyapon Poolsawasd",
   thumbnail: "http://www.youweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/image.png"

Comment: it does return something

Answer (score 0):

**Your Data:**

```
[ { 
title: "Post From Wordpress Title", 
content: "Some Content from Post on Wordpress", 
author: "Banyapon Poolsawasd", thumbnail: "" 
},{ 
title: "Post From Wordpress Title", 
content: "Some Content from Post on Wordpress", 
author: "Banyapon Poolsawasd", 
thumbnail: "" 
 } ]
```

In above case your data starts from `NSArray` and **not `NSDictionary`**.That is the reason nothing is displayed.

Use below code to get **Title** and other values as follows e.g.

```
 NSLog(@"Title :%@",[[jsonObjects objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"title"]);
```